# Recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml)

Tags: python, opencv

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue.

```
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\facerec.cpp:61: error: (-2:Unspecified error) File can't be opened for reading! in function 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer::read'
```

recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cv2.error:

> OpenCV(4.1.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\facerec.cpp:61:
>   error: (-2:Unspecified error) File can't be opened for reading! in
>   function 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer::read'

Comment: The error is ' File can't be opened for reading!'. It means that the code can not open 'trainer/trainer.yml' for read. It may be a permission issue or file location issue.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the file 'trainer/trainer.yml'
you will need to download it and place it in the path /trainer/